# Form freezing on async backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Been searching all over for an answer to this, but I can t figure it out. I'm not as familiar with C# as some other languages and any info will help. No matter what I try the form freezes up when running the backgroundworker.

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(filepath);

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = e.Argument.ToString();

        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filepath))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                e.Result = base64String;
            }
        }  
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: is it freezed for one second?

Comment: Remove System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: What do you mean by the form freezing up?  Does it stop responding to user input?  Does it stop redrawing?  Or do you just mean that it doesn't do anything interesting until the worker completes?

Comment: The call to `Sleep` is inside the background worker, I don't see why that would lock up the UI.  I feel that there is some more code you aren't showing us.  What causes your BackgroundWorker to get called?

Comment: I just have backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(filepath); inside a button click. filepath is a string (string filepath = toolStripLabel1.Text;) Originally I didnt have the Thread.Sleep. It freezes up the UI either way

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correctly. However, you are suspending your background thread for the 1 second. To avoid this behaviour you should just delete this row of code:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: That's inside the BackgroundWorker.  If the worker is actually executing asynchronously that shouldn't affect the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using async/await as Microsoft recomends using it in place of BackgroundWorker.

Assuming your worker is being triggered inside a button click event, it would look like this:

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filepath))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    return base64String;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: While helpful, it doesn't really answer the question though.  The OP needs to respond to your comment.

Comment: Thank you, but using that async/await code seems to work the same as the background worker. The form still freezes until the operation is complete

Comment: None of the methods you are using should be freezing the UI.  There must be something in code that you haven't shown us.